# Finding HTML table row by class name using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to keep the serial number to stay with the sequence after I remove any HTML table's row.

```
 $("#trid_"+a_href).remove();

 $("tr").each(function (index) {
     if(index != 0) { 
    $(this).find("td:first").html(index + ""); 
    }
});
```

The code is working okay but the problem is it is displaying serial numbers for all the rows in the table. 
But I want to display only in the rows where `<tr class="products">`

My guess is, to solve this problem I have to find the `class="products"` in tr, so I have tried the following code, but this time the code didn't work at all.

```
$("#trid_"+a_href).remove();

 $(".products tr").each(function (index) {
     if(index != 0) { 
    $(this).find("td:first").html(index + ""); 
    }
});
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

### Edit

My entire Code is too large. So I have uploaded the script [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByuynjwYX5xAd3BfMmpKY0dXZk0)

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you show your HTML code as well?

Comment: I think you just need to change it to `$('tr.products').each(....` but I need to see the HTML to be sure

Comment: @Ohad, Thanks for your reply. I am going to update my answer by providing the html. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ohad Would you please check the edited part of my question? THanks

Answer (score 1):

The right selector is :

```
$("tr.products").each ...
```

`".products tr"` selects all the tr elements, which are descendants of any node having the "products" class

`"tr.products"` (no space between `tr` and `.poducts`) selects all the tr nodes which have the "products" classe (which is what you want here)

`"tr .products"` would select all the elements having class ".products", which are descendants of a tr node

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried both `"tr.products"` `"tr .products"` but its not solving my problem. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I have included rest of my scripts in the edited part of my question. would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr.products").each(function (index) {
   $(this).find("td:first").html(index); 
});
```